# jqgrid ie8 multiple search filter not picking search data when using cmTemplate

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

using ie8, jqgrid 4.3.3, jquery 1.7.2 or 1.5.2, multiple search seems to miss some search parameters. 
on adding a new search row for the 1st time, it appears in the request body but with a blank value ("")
such as.

```
"filters":"{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"code\",\"op\":\"eq\",\"data\":\"\"}]}",
```

subsequent search with the same parameters sends the correct vlaue.
My basic setup is as follows (simplified)

```
$('#Table').jqGrid({
         //....
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Code'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'Code',
        index: 'Code'}],
    pager: '#Pager'
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#Pager', {
    add: false,
    edit: false,
    del: false,
    refresh: false
}, {}, {}, {}, {
    multipleSearch: true
}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

**UPDATED:** added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwachira/CH5rZ)

after a long time, I found that the error happens only if I am using cmTemplate to specify searchoptions sopt and when I click on 'find' without 1st clicking outside the data text box. 
[See jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pwachira/CH5rZ) (remember to click the find button directly after typing the search value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, it's an old bug with refreshing of jqGrid input fields which I described [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/search-dialog-from-jqgrid-4-3-2-can-ignore-the-last-entered-data/#p26339). You can try to insert the following callback

```
afterRedraw: function () {
    $(this).find(".input-elm").triggerHandler('change', [true]);
}
```

like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U6BPx/5/). You can also try to use jqGrid 4.4.1 instead of 4.3.3. The version should have no such problems.

**UPDATED**: I found that my previously posted and committed changes was reverted back: see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/d37ff42d23350d58de04300adccbc37805f82aec). My suggestions  was collection of many improvements:

1. the style of buttons in the searching dialog was used like in jQuery UI and in all other parts of jqGrid. One could use `uiButtons: false` to use the old style.
2. one could change the default names "+", "-" and "+ {}" buttons and the tooltips which are all in English only in the current version of jqGrid (`'Add rule'`, `'Delete rule'`, `'Add subgroup'`, `'Delete group'`).
3. The focus will be additionally set to input controls or buttons. It allows to use searching dialog with the keyboards only without require to use mouse.
4. It will be triggered `"change"` events on all input controls before the final reading of data from the searching dialog.

The last changes could be important to fix your problem.

One should modify the implementation of the [filterData](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.filter.js#L694-702) function. One should add the lines

```
$(this).find(".input-elm").each(function() {
    $(this).triggerHandler("change");
});
```

before [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.filter.js#L698).

The problem is that jqGrid bind 'change' event to all input fields of the searching dialog (see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.filter.js#L409-417)). After the user type the data for the searching the 'change' event will be triggered and the internal data `filter` (see `rule.data`, which is the part of the `filter`, in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.filter.js#L413)) will be modified. If the user click on Search button the *current* value of `filter` will be get (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L227)). The problem is that the `change` event will be processed in some web browsers **after** processing of the `'click'` event on the "Search" button. So the input data from the last searching filter could be not yet set. The call of `.triggerHandler("change")` on all input controls *before* the data from the `filter` will be returned could fix the problem. In the case some unneeded `change` events could be called, but one will be sure that the data in `filter` are the same as the data from the.

I think that [reverting of the changes](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/d37ff42d23350d58de04300adccbc37805f82aec) was the bad idea.

If one would use `searchOnEnter: true` option the usage of `.triggerHandler("change")` and to start searching with <kbd>Enter</kbd> key the problem should not take place because of [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L205)

```
$("#"+fid+"_search").focus().click();
```

where the focus will be explicitly set to "Search" button before processing of the click event. In the way the `"change"` event will be indirectly triggered and the data in the `filter` will be refreshed.

I think that one can fix the problem which you described without direct triggering of `change` events. Instead of that one can include explicit setting of the focus

```
$("#"+fid+"_search").focus();
```

inside of `click` event handler (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L224)). It's important to do this *before* [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L227) where `.jqFilter('filterData')` will be called.

Comment: @chohi: You should include the callback on the same level where you defines `multipleSearch: true`. Look at the code in [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U6BPx/5/). It's callback of the [searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options).

Comment: Using the latest grid 4.4.1 and jquery 1.7.2 - No can do @oleg, after redraw fires before I edit the new filter row, notwithstanding that, logging the val() of input-elm shows my new values, do I need a handle to the function that extends postdata with filters selected?

Comment: @chohi: I am not sure that I understand you. The problem which I describe should be fixed in jqGrid 4.4.1. You can try to set breakpoint on [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L227) of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and verify that [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.filter.js#L504) will be called after the user fill the data to filter. You can post the working demo or URL which reproduces the described problem.

Comment: Hi @oleg , src works fine, can it be different from minified ? I ll get time to switch back and forth to verify later today

Comment: @chohi: It sounds strange that the problem exist only in minified version of jqGrid. You can use for example you can get `AjaxMin.exe` from http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/ and use it to minify `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`, CSS and other files. During minitying of locale files like grid.locale-en.js, grid.locale-de.js you should uses `-enc:in utf-8 -enc:out utf-8` additional switches.

Comment: found it was due to not blurring out of the data field - how can I force this and at what point?

Comment: @chohi: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean. Could you express yourself more clear? Which "data field" you mean? What problem  is with the fields and how I can help you?

Comment: I added searchrules:{required:true}. if i add a new filter row and type in the search value and directly click find, I get a validation error. if i type in the value, click outside the value textbox the click find, the search works

Comment: @chohi: Could you provide the demo which reproduces the problem. In the demo you should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` from jqGrid 4.4.1 and describe how the problem could be reproduced (which browser etc). If I could reproduce the problem I could fry to find the reason.

Comment: @chohi: I found now that my suggestion which fixed the problem was revert back (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/d37ff42d23350d58de04300adccbc37805f82aec)). It's important for you [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/d37ff42d23350d58de04300adccbc37805f82aec#L0L761). I think that one have to add some lines before [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.filter.js#L698). One have to trigger `'change'` event is the focus has the field having `"input-elm"` class.

Comment: @chohi: I added **"UPDATED"** part in my answer where I described more detailed the reason of the problem and how it could be solved.

Comment: see updated jsfiddle, it had to do with cmTemplate having searchoptions andd sopt,

Comment: @chohi: I tried the demo, but I can't reproduce the error. What I don't understand is: why you don't follow my suggestion and not just includes `$("#"+fid+"_search").focus();` or just `$(this).focus();` as the first statement of the `click` event handler (direct after [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L224))? It's important to do this **before** call of `filterData` in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L227). I tried to explain the problem in my answer. Just try it and  verify that the problem is fixed.

Comment: @chohi: [The file](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqgrid-4.4.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.src-search.js) is the modification of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` which just includes `$(this).focus();` as the first line of the `$("#"+fid+"_search").click` handler. Try to reproduce the problem with the file or to confirm that the change fix your problem.

Comment: solution does not work - it looks like it should - but just does not. on debuging the filter has a blank value

Comment: @chohi: It's strange, but I had never the problem. What could be different in our tests? Which web browser and in which version you use?

Comment: IE8 is the problem -other browsers work fine I added instructions in jsfiddle

Comment: @chohi: The problem is that I could *never* reproduce the described problem if I use http://jsfiddle.net/pwachira/CH5rZ and followed the instruction which you described. Everything worked always correctly in both IE8 and in IE9 (on another computer) working in IE8 compatibility mode. Moreover I couldn't imagine that the usage of `cmTemplate` could be important here because `cmTemplate` just extend the `colModel` (see [the only line of the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2153) where `cmTemplate` are used).